"Is there a relayer or a way to communicate Polkadot with Hyperledger Fabric?"
I am doing a project and I want to know if there is a stable relayer or bridge to connect both blockchains, so each one can read transactions to validate some operations.
I found a project that tries to do this, I think, but it is still in development. Does anyone have any ideas?
